# ssh between two EC2 instances

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, key-pair, ssh-keygen

I've got two EC2 instances and I'm trying to see if I can ssh from one to another.

If I try from my Windows instance to PuTTY each of them it works( by providing the .ppk file).

Now, both instances were associated to the same key-pair and if I chekc in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` there is the same public key(obviously because it refers to the same Key-pair that I generated in AWS).

I tried to `ssh <other host>` but it asks me for a passphrase of the key which doesn't exist.

SO what I did now is to create a key-pair from instance A with `ssh-keygen`, then I tried

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please if you have any ideas they are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `ssh-copy-id` if the only authentication method you have is `publickey`.

When you generated the key on the first instance, you need to copy public part from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the other instances `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Yes eventually I did everything manually and finally it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as a solution if it was useful for you.

Comment: I did this and it did not work for me. What could I be missing?

Comment: @dewwwald if you created these files, probably permissions or you wrote the keys wrongly. Hard to guess.

Comment: @Jakuje it was strage as it did not work when the ssh key was named anything but id_rsa.pub. So i generated a key with the default name and it worked... So weird.

Comment: @dewwwald the ssh client is using the keys with default names out of the box. If you name your key differently, it will not work (unless you configure your client to use the key in different location).

Comment: Makes sense. I'll go check out changing the ssh default config.